# Searching Multiple Keywords with foreach in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Here is my code:

```
$this->Product->recursive = 0;
    foreach ($search_array as $value){
        $search = $this->Product->find('all', array (
        'contain' => array('Picture' => array('limit' => 1),
                           'User',
                           'Category',
                           'Vote'
                          ),
        'conditions' =>array("OR" => 
                                    array("Product.name LIKE" => "%".$value."%",
                                          "Product.description LIKE" => "%".$value."%")
                            )
    ));
    }
    $this->set('search', $search);
}
```

this method returns only the last keyword. For example if someone search for "mobile app", this method search for "app" only.
How can be solved this problem?

Comment: print once your database query and check the where condition in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use only last search results. You perform searches inside `foreach` loop but use only last value of `$search`. In this situation you also able to have PHP error because of using `$search` value which can be undefined in some circumstances (when `$search_array` is empty, for example).

You need to use `foreach` for generating `LIKE` conditions and then use this conditions in query.

```
$this->Product->recursive = 0;

$or_condition = array();

foreach ($search_array as $value){
    $or_condition[] = array_merge($or_condition, array(
        array("Product.name LIKE" => "%$value%"),
        array("Product.description LIKE" => "%$value%")
    ));
}

$search = array();

if (!empty($or_condition)) {
    $search = $this->Product->find('all', array (
        'contain' => array(
            'Picture' => array('limit' => 1),
            'User',
            'Category',
            'Vote'
        ),
        'conditions' => array("OR" => $or_condition)
    ));
}

$this->set('search', $search);
```

So, when somebody will search for "mobile app", you will have this condition:

```
[
    'contain' => [
        'Picture' => array('limit' => 1),
        'User',
        'Category',
        'Vote'
    ],
    'conditions' => [
        "OR" => [
            ["Product.name LIKE" => "%mobile%"],
            ["Product.description LIKE" => "%mobile%"],
            ["Product.name LIKE" => "%app%"],
            ["Product.description LIKE" => "%app%"]
        ]
    ]
]
```